# How to center Text in Canvas in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am creating a custom composable in Jetpack Compose using Canvas.
How to center text when using `drawText`?

**Code**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyCenterTextInCanvas() {
    val width: Dp = 200.dp
    val height: Dp = 40.dp
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .wrapContentSize(
                align = Alignment.Center,
            )
            .requiredSize(
                width = width,
                height = height,
            ),
    ) {
        drawText(
            textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
            text = "Sample Text",
            topLeft = Offset(
                x = (width / 2).toPx(),
                y = (height / 2).toPx(),
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

**Compose version**
jetpackComposeVersion = "1.3.0-alpha02"

**UI**

[image]

Comment: It's very good to see they finally added drawing text to Canvas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it by measuring text and placing it as

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTextApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyCenterTextInCanvas() {
    val width: Dp = 200.dp
    val height: Dp = 40.dp
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()

    val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult =
        textMeasurer.measure(text = AnnotatedString("Sample Text"))
    val textSize = textLayoutResult.size
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .requiredSize(
                width = width,
                height = height,
            ),
    ) {

        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height


        drawText(
            textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
            text = "Sample Text",
            topLeft = Offset(
                (canvasWidth - textSize.width) / 2f,
                (canvasHeight - textSize.height) / 2f
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. . I did not know how to use Text Measurer.

Comment: Although the centerling logic is correct, please do not measure text in composition. Ideally text measuring should be a part of the layout phase. Also, measured text should be remembered/cached. You can use Modifier.drawWithCache on a Box instead of Canvas composable to cache a `TextLayoutResult`. If you check the source code of Canvas, you'll see there's nothing special to it. 

In any case, TextMeasurer caches results internally by default. If attributes do not change, text layout will be skipped and result will be returned from the internal cache.

Comment: @HalilIbrahimOzercan sure, canvas is nothing but Spacer with Modifier.drawContent but how can we move  text measurement to layout phase? In this answer i moved measurement of text to remember. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73547525/5457853. Is this correct? Also would you mind posting examples with layout phase and `Modifier.drawWithCache`?