# How to create watermark text effect in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, watermark

I would like to create a watermark effect in my app using text as shown in the picture below.
I achieved this by using canvas and bitmap, is there any other reliable way to do this?

[image]

Here is my composable function

```
@Composable
fun WaterMark(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  content: (@Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit)? = null,
) {

  val watermarkText: String = "some mutable text"

  val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
  paint.textSize = LocalContext.current.dpToPx(24).toFloat()
  paint.color = PSCoreColours.psCoreColours.onSurface.hashCode()
  paint.textAlign = Paint.Align.LEFT
  paint.alpha = (255 * 0.25).toInt()
  val baseline: Float = -paint.ascent()
  val image: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(paint.measureText(watermarkText).toInt(),
    (baseline + paint.descent()).toInt(),
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

  val canvas = android.graphics.Canvas(image)
  canvas.drawText(watermarkText, 0f, baseline, paint)
  val rotationMatrix: Matrix = Matrix().apply { postRotate(-45f) }

  val rotatedImage: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, rotationMatrix, true)

  val pattern: ImageBitmap = rotatedImage.asImageBitmap()

  Box {
    content?.let { it() }
    Canvas(
      modifier = modifier
    ) {
      val totalWidth = size.width / pattern.width
      val totalHeight = size.height / pattern.height
      var x = 0f
      var y = 0f
      for (i in 0..totalHeight.toInt()) {
        y = (i * pattern.height).toFloat()
        for (j in 0..totalWidth.toInt()) {
          x = (j * pattern.width).toFloat()
          drawImage(
            pattern,
            colorFilter = null,
            topLeft = Offset(x, y),
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do custom layouts in compose for this

```kotlin
private const val SPACING = 100

@Composable
fun Watermark(
  content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit,
) {
  Box {
    content()

    Layout(
      content = {
        // Repeating the placeables, 6 should do for now but we should be able to calculate this too
        repeat(6) { 
          Text(
            text = watermarkText,
            ..
          )
        }
      }
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
      // Measuring all the placables
      val placeables: List<Placeable> = measurables
        .map { measurable -> measurable.measure(constraints) }
        
      layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
        // Calculating the max width of a placable
        val maxWidth: Double = placeables.maxOf { it.width }.toDouble()

        // Calculating the max width of a tile given the text is rotated
        val tileSize: Int = (constraints.maxWidth / atan(maxWidth)).toInt()
        
        placeables
          .chunked(2)  // Placing 2 columns 
          .forEachIndexed { index, (first, second) ->
            val indexedTileSize: Int = index * tileSize
            first.placeRelativeWithLayer(-SPACING, indexedTileSize + SPACING) { rotationZ = -45f }
            second.placeRelativeWithLayer(tileSize, indexedTileSize) { rotationZ = -45f }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Watermark function creates instance of `Paint` and `Bitmap` on each recomposition. You should wrap them with remember as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375906/5457853).

However you might, i think, do what you do fully Compose way without `Paint` and `Bitmap` either `using Modifier.drawWithContent{}` and `drawText` function of `DrawScope` and using `translate` or `rotate` inside `DrawScope`.

This is a [drawText sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73547525/5457853) to understand how you can create and store `TextLayoutResult` remember.

And another [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73590696/5457853) using `Modifier.drawWithContent`

You can also try using `Modifier.drawWithCache` to cache TextLayoutResult in layout phase instead of composition phase which is suggested by Google Compose developer works on Text [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73352227/5457853)